# Proving conditions for controllability

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems, system-identification, linear-algebra, proof

Let's say I have the following LTI system: 
$$\dot{x}(t) = \mathbf{A} x(t) + \mathbf{B} u(t)$$
I need to somehow show the following is true or false (proof):

This system is controllable if and only if for any $\mu$ such that $(−\mu\mathbf{I − A})$ is [Hurwitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix), there exists a unique positive deﬁnite solution $\mathbf W$ to the Lyapunov equation:

$$\mathbf A \mathbf W + \mathbf W \mathbf A^T − \mathbf B\mathbf B^T = −2\mu\mathbf W$$

Can anyone see the proof? I tried replacing $\mathbf A$ in the Lyapunov equation with $(−\mu\mathbf I − \mathbf A)$, and then adding the $−2\mu\mathbf W$, to the left side, but the $\mu$'s end up cancelling out, so I'm not sure. 
I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your definition of controllable?

Comment: Well normally I would say that the controllability matrix (which has the form R =[B, AB, A^2B, ....A^(n-1)B]) is full rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required step you were looking for seems to be grouping each $\mu W$ with $A$. Denote the inverse of $W$ with $P$. Then pre and post multiply the Lyapunov equation with P. Then

$$
0 = (\mu I +A)W + W(\mu I + A)^T - BB^T
$$
From here you can negate the equation and use the textbook arguments about the grammians of controllability. Hurwitz property implies the positive definiteness of $W$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a direct help, but [this paper](http://tsakalis.faculty.asu.edu/notes/sco.pdf) might provide some insight, particularly the paragraph below.

[image]